# PHP if statment on array length not working

Tags: php

here is my code :

```
  elseif (is_dir($dir)) {
      $scanning = scandir($dir);
      $okdir;
      // $response["scan"] = $scanning;
      foreach ($scanning as $key=> $value) {
        $splitscan = explode("_",$scanning[$key]);

        if ($splitscan[0] == $searchvalue ){
          $okdir[] = $scanning[$key];
          if (count($okdir)>1){
            $response["okdir"] = $okdir;
            $response["result"] = "more";

          }
          else {
            $okdir = $okdir[0];
          }

        }
      }
```

when the function goes on the else statment i get no problem, but when the conditions need to verify the if statment `if(count($okdir>1))` i get PHP internal error. What does it mean? That the if statment is never true? What i'm doing wrong?
Thank you for any help provided

Here is the error log answer:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings

Here is the whole function:

```
private function pdf(){

    $response;
    $dir = "../Pdf/";
    $searchvalue = $this->params["utentericercato"];
    if (!isset($_COOKIE["idutente"])){
      $response["result"] = "nosession";
      $utente->setUteLogged(false);
    }

    // Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
    elseif (is_dir($dir)) {
      $scanning = scandir($dir);
      $okdir = array();
      // $response["scan"] = $scanning;
      foreach ($scanning as $key=> $value) {
        $splitscan = explode("_",$scanning[$key]);

        if ($splitscan[0] == $searchvalue ){
          $okdir[] = $scanning[$key];
          if (count($okdir)>1){
            $response["okdir"] = $okdir;
            $response["result"] = "more";

          }
          else {
            $okdir = $okdir[0];
          }

        }
      }
      if (empty($okdir)){
        $response["result"]= "noutente";
      }
      else {
        $newdir = $dir.$okdir;
        $nomeutente = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z\s]/", "", $okdir);
        $response["dir"] = $newdir;
        $response["nomeutente"] = $nomeutente;
        if (is_dir($newdir)){
          $dh = array_diff(scandir($newdir),array(".",".."));
          $arr = is_array($dh);


          $x = 0;
          while($x < sizeof($dh)){
            foreach($dh as $key=>$value){
              if ($key[$value] != "." && $key[$value] != ".."){
                $response["files"][$key] = $value;
                $response["result"] = "success";
              }

              $x = $x + 1;
            }
          }

        }
      }


    }
    else {
      $response["result"] = "nodirectory";
    }

    Responder::giveResponse($response);
  }
```

Comment: Give us the verbatim error message, possibly from the log files.

Comment: possibly, `$okdir` becomes a non-array object at some point. Check `else { $okdir = $okdir[0]; }`. `count()` will throw an error if $okdir is not something you can count, like an array.

Comment: @erickb   `else { $okdir = $okdir[0]; }` is working because my script goes on on this statment, this means thath `$okdir` is still an array, isn't it?

Comment: _sidenote:_ this line `$okdir;` does nothing. (but you define $okdir later anyway)

Comment: As an aside, I recommend searching for `$searchvalue . '_'` at offset 0 with `strpos()` instead of exploding.

Comment: @Jeff you are right , but it is not relevant to the problem i guess

Comment: `$okdir = $okdir[0];` changes the data type from array to string.  Why would you want to do this inside your loop? Do it after... if at all.  I cannot replicate your issue.

Comment: What did you intend with `$okdir = $okdir[0];`? If you want to reduce the array to the first element for some reason, `$okdir = [$okdir[0]];` would be the correct syntax.

Comment: At the point `$newdir = $dir.$okdir;` `$okdir` might be an array as well. And why do you reference `$splitscan = explode("_",$scanning[$key]);` by key when you have the `$value`?

Comment: This all looks a little bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What did you really intend to achieve?

Comment: the problem is that `$serchvalue` colud lead to more folders with the same initial string for example: 100106_106_user1 and 100106_105_user2. I need that when this happens the script stops and send me a response with the two values found.

Comment: You need only the first match? Then the `break` statement is your friend. As discussed below in the answers, `glob` is the much better function. It provides a `GLOB_NOSORT` and a `GLOB_MARK` flag.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone i need all the matches with `$searchvalue`, because when there is only one my script works perfectly

Comment: As long as it is not the last entry since otherwise an array is used for string concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first iteration sets the variable as a string.  Any subsequent iteration will attempt to "push" data into the string like it is an array.

Demo:  https://3v4l.org/GOdgs

```
$scanning[0] = "b";
$okdir = "a";           // just add [] after $okdir
$okdir[] = $scanning[0];
var_export($okdir);
```

I suppose I recommend that you just remove:

```
      else {
        $okdir = $okdir[0];
      }
```

It only causes trouble.

And...

```
if (count($okdir)>1){
    $response["okdir"] = $okdir;
    $response["result"] = "more";
}
```

Should be positioned after your loop so that it is executed only once.

---

If this were my project, I'd be doing something like `chdir($dir);` then `glob("{$searchvalue}_*")` <-- grab and filter in the same step.

Comment: sorry , i don't understand,  on wich line in my code i should add [] ?

Comment: Im not using any curly braced expressions in my glob, that flag is not needed.  Maybe `glob($searchvalue . "_*")` is easier to read

Comment: I've tried your answer, it changes nothing. I'm just getting no error but the script does not do what i want.
The problem is that `$serchvalue` could lead to more folders with the same initial string for example: 100106_106_user1 and 100106_105_user2. I need that when this happens the script stops and send me a response with the two values found.

Comment: That's a correct answer. +1. I've implemented an example of the suggested approach with `glob` since I can no longer see the disaster around this question. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I did not test it yet, however, this much cleaner approach should work. At least it should give you an idea how to do the task in a structured way.

```
private function pdf()
{
  $response    = [];
  $dir         = "../Pdf/";
  $searchvalue = $this->params["utentericercato"];

  if (is_dir($dir))
  {
    chdir($dir);
    $okdir = glob("{$searchvalue}_*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    switch (count($okdir))
    {
      case 0:
        $response['result']     = 'noutente';
        break;

      case 1:
        $nomeutente             = preg_replace("/[^a-z\s]/i", "", $okdir[0]);
        $response["dir"]        = $dir . $okdir[0];
        $response["nomeutente"] = $nomeutente;

        chdir($okdir[0]);
        $response["files"]      = glob('*');
        if(!empty($response["files"]))
        {
          $response["result"]     = "success";
        }
        break;

      default:
        $response["okdir"]      = $okdir; // or $okdir[0] if you do not want an array but the first item
        $response["result"]     = "more";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $response["result"] = "nodirectory";
  }
  Responder::giveResponse($response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the error log answer: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings

To fix the error above, define `$okdir` as array.

Line no 3 should be changed from `$okdir;` to `$okdir = array();`

Comment: _"variable define as string by default"_ - I cannot find that in the manual, nor does a [quick test](https://3v4l.org/ckv88) show what you state!

Comment: I've tried to well-form the answer without touching the author's intention.

Comment: I've tried as you say, i've defined it as array but still not working and getting PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: Actually the variable `$okdir` was *used* in line 3 and not declared at all. A notice 'Undefined variable' should be thrown. However, defining it as an array (partially) is a correct answer even if this does not solve the problem entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, old code not working:

```
elseif (is_dir($dir)) {
  $scanning = scandir($dir);
  $okdir = array();
  // $response["scan"] = $scanning;
  foreach ($scanning as $key=> $value) {
    $splitscan = explode("_",$scanning[$key]);

    if ($splitscan[0] == $searchvalue ){
      $okdir[] = $scanning[$key];
      if (count($okdir)>1){
        $response["okdir"] = $okdir;
        $response["result"] = "more";

      }
      else {
        $okdir = $okdir[0];
      }

    }
  }
  if (empty($okdir)){
    $response["result"]= "noutente";
  }
```

new working code :

```
elseif (is_dir($dir)) {
      $scanning = scandir($dir);
      $okdir = array();
      // $response["scan"] = $scanning;
      foreach ($scanning as $key=> $value) {
        $splitscan = explode("_",$scanning[$key]);

        if ($splitscan[0] == $searchvalue ){
          $okdir[] = $scanning[$key];



        }

      }

      if (count($okdir)>1){
        $response["okdir"] = $okdir;
        $response["result"] = "more";
        Responder::giveResponse($response);
        exit;

      }
      if (empty($okdir)){
        $response["result"]= "noutente";
      }
```

Comment: Your new code correctly uses the first suggestion in my answer.  You may accept my answer if you like.  See my comment under your question about avoiding the explosiom step.  `strpos()` is simpler / more direct.

Comment: `$scanning[$key]` is more simply written as `$value` and this allows you to omit the `$key` declaration in your loop.